# Intuitive scroll for embedded browser in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, scroll, touch

I am working on a project built in WPF, which includes an embedded WebBrowser. The Browser that comes with WPF did not meet our needs, so we are using a WinForms WebBrowser in a WindowsFormsHost element.

This all works fine, except the application is to be used on a touch screen, and the users are having a hard time using the tiny standard scrollbar supplied by IE.

I know how to scroll programmatically, but how would you supply a more user-friendly scrolling mechanism? Only constraint is that I cannot overlay anything over the WebBrowser, and there is no room beside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a old Code Project article that shows a way to modify scroll bar size. The article is in C++, I think it might be possible to adapt the technique by subclassing the browser window using winAPI, but I don't think it's going to be easy.

[ResizeScrollbar - How to change width of built-in scroll bars](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/resizescrollbar.aspx)

Also there's the possibility to modify the scrollbar size at system level ...

Comment: I was unaware of the Windows setting for scrollbar size. Since the system is only to be used for touch-input, we'll go with this solution.

Thank you very much!